# Jquery hide current div content, then load new content, then show new content

Tags: jquery, click, load, hide, show

Possible to hide current div content, then load new content, then show new content on jquery click?

here's the page:

```
<div id="menu">
<ol>
<li><a id="anchor1" href="#content_jump_point">Blah Blah Blah</a></li>
</ol>
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

The css is standard and not relevant to the question, but here is some anyway:

```
#menu{
float:left;
clear:both;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: 100%
height:auto;
}

#content{
float:left;
clear:both;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: 100%
height:auto;
}
```

The html loaded to the div when the page first loads

```
first_stuff.html

<h1> Stuff that gets loaded when the page loads</h1>
<p> lorem*20 </p>
```

The html that loads after the anchor1 is clicked:
    second_stuff.html

```
<h1> Stuff that slides in after the stuff above slides out</h1>
<p> lorem*10 </p>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

The init function is also loaded with src but here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(init);

function init(){

$('#content').load('/content/first_stuff.html');    

$("#anchor1").click(function(){

$('#content').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},1000);

$('#content').load('/content/second_stuff.html').show("slide",
{direction:"left"},1000);

});//end click function

};//end init

</script>
```

The problem is that within the click function the html is loaded to the content div before the content is hidden. So rather than 'first_stuff.html' sliding out to the right and 'second_stuff.html' sliding in from the left, 'second_stuff.html' loads instantly then slides out to the right and slides in again from the left.

We want 'first_stuff.html' to slide out to the right, then 'second_stuff.html' to slide in from the left, on the same click of the anchor.

We've tried a number of things and searched the web thoroughly. Greatly appreciate any wizzdom.

For example, we tried putting '.show()' in a callback function for the '.load()' method, or loading the HTML from the content div to a variable before the click function is called, then hiding that variable and loading stuff to content div.

Comment: Why do not you try to load the second html with little delay using `setTimeout` function ?

Comment: Thanks. Tried both delay and setTimout, neither worked but probably would if the order of element to object conversion was correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works: 
 $('#content').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},1000,function(){$('#content').loa‌​‌​d('second_stuff.html')}); 
 $('#content').show("slide",{direction:"left"},1000);

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
$('#content').show("slide",{direction:"left"},1000,function(){$('#content').load('second_stuff.html')});
```

first hide div then show div after that load contents in it.

Comment: This was close. first_stuff.html slides out of view, then slides in and is replaced by second_stuff.html.